Reduce background noise from mic audio
I am developing a live stream application in flutter. We are working on a feature which streams live audio from microphone to RTMP server. Here how to reduce background noise from the mic audio while streaming to RTMP server.
Configuration of audio session:
AudioSessionConfiguration(
      avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.voiceChat,
      avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord,
      avAudioSessionCategoryOptions:
      AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker,

      androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
        contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.speech,
        flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
        usage: AndroidAudioUsage.voiceCommunication,
      ),
      androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain,
    )

